# build inverted index in spark application using scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and scala programming language. My input is a **CSV file**. I need to build an **inverted index** on the values in csv file like explained below with an example.

```
Input: file.csv

attr1, attr2, attr3
1,     AAA,    23
2,     BBB,    23
3,     AAA,    27

output format: value -> (rowid, columnid) pairs
for example: AAA -> ((1,2),(3,2))
             27  -> (3,3)
```

I have started with the following code. I am stuck after that. Kindly help.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Invert Me!").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    
    val txtFilePath = "/home/person/Desktop/sample.csv"
    
    val txtFile = sc.textFile(txtFilePath)
    val nRows = txtFile.count()
      
    val data = txtFile.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim()))
    val nCols = data.collect()(0).length
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code preserving your style could look as

```
val header = sc.broadcast(data.first())

val cells = data.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 > 0).flatMap { case (row, index) =>
  row.zip(header.value).map { case (value, column) => value ->(column, index) }
}


val index: RDD[(String, Vector[(String, Long)])] = 
   cells.aggregateByKey(Vector.empty[(String, Long)])(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)
```

Here the `index` value should contain desired mapping of `CellValue` to pair `(ColumnName, RowIndex)`

Underscores in above methods are just shortcutted lambdas, it could be written another way as

```
val cellsVerbose = data.zipWithIndex().flatMap {
  case (row, 1) => IndexedSeq.empty // skipping header row
  case (row, index) => row.zip(header.value).map {
    case (value, column) => value ->(column, index)
  }
} 


val indexVerbose: RDD[(String, Vector[(String, Long)])] =
  cellsVerbose.aggregateByKey(zeroValue = Vector.empty[(String, Long)])(
    seqOp = (keys, key) => keys :+ key,
    combOp = (keysA, keysB) => keysA ++ keysB)
```

Comment: since i am new to scala, i am taking time to grasp all the underscores in the above code..will get back to you in case of any further help..thanks

Comment: @CRM provided little bit more verbose version